# Change font on mouse over and revert font back when mousing over a second time

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, mouseover

I'm looking for a way to change the font on individual letters when mousing over them. I want the individual letters to change back to their original font when you mouse over them a second time (not when you mouse away for the first time).

Any and all help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### By using classList

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)

```js
var elLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < elLi.length; i++){
  elLi[i].onmouseover = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("times");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.times {
  font-family: 'Times';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

#### Without classList

```js
var elLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < elLi.length; i++){
  elLi[i].onmouseover = function(){
    if (hasClass(this, 'times')) {
     this.className = "";
      // Remove class
    } else {
      // Add class
      this.className = "times";
    }
  }
}

function hasClass( target, className ) {
    return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(target.className);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.times {
  font-family: 'Times';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's simple jQuery example

```
var hoveredCounter = 0;
$('.post-text').hover(function(){

    //hover in
    hoveredCounter++;
    //console.log(hoveredCounter);

    if(hoveredCounter == 1){
        $(this).addClass('new-font');//or $(this).css('font-family', 'Arial');
    } else if(hoveredCounter == 2) {
        $(this).removeClass('new-font');//or $(this).css('font-family', 'Verdana');
    }
}, function(){
    //hover out
})

.old-font{
    font-family: "Arial";
}

.old-font.new-font{ /* using 2 classnames so the rule will have bigger priority*/
    font-family: "Verdana"
}
```

if you want each letter to be changeable you'll need separate `<span>` for each. you can automate that via https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js